# How to download several files with GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, urllib, webapp2

I'd like to download several files with GAE Python code.
My current code is like below

```
import webapp2, urllib
url1 = 'http://dummy/sample1.jpg'
url2 = 'http://dummy/sample2.jpg'

class DownloadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #image1
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + 'sample1.jpg' + '"'
        f = urllib.urlopen(url1)
        data = f.read()
        self.response.out.write(data)

        #image2
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + 'sample2.jpg' + '"'
        f = urllib.urlopen(url2)
        data = f.read()
        self.response.out.write(data)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', DownloadHandler)], 
                              debug=True)
```

I expected to occur download dialogue twice with this code, but actually occurred once, and only sample2.jpg was downloaded.
How can you handle download dialogue several times?

I'd actually like to realize some other functions adding above as well.
To display progressing message on the browser such as
 sample1.jpg was downloaded
 sample2.jpg was downloaded
 sample3.jpg was downloaded ...

And redirect to the other page after downloading files.
When I wrote a code such as

```
self.redirect('/otherpage')
```

after

```
self.response.out.write(data)
```

Only redirect had happened and didn't occur download procedure.

Would you give me any ideas to solve it please.
I'm using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You cannot write two files in one response that has a `Content-Type` of `application/octet-stream`. To stuff multiple files in in the response, you would have to encode your response with `multipart/form-data` or `multipart/mixed` and hope that the client would understand that and parse it and show two download dialogues
2. Once you've already called `self.response.out.write(…)`, you shouldn't be setting any more headers.

To me it seems that the most foolproof option would be to serve an HTML file that contains something like:

```
<script>
  window.open('/path/to/file/1.jpg');
  window.open('/path/to/file/1.jpg');
</script>
```

… and then handle those paths using different handlers.

Another option would be to zip the two files and serve the zipfile to the client, though it may or may not be preferable in your case.

Comment: Thank you, Attila.
I tried to replace Content-Type from application/octet-stream to multipart/form-data, but the result was the same before.

Comment: I'll try to use the way with <script> tag.

I'd like to make downloader function at the end, such as search image with cats on google, and then 100 or 1000 images are automatically downloaded.
If download dialogue occurred 1000 times, it's too annoying, so I will zip some files, however I guess it will be huge file if zip all the file at once. So I'm trying to handle several download dialogues.

Comment: 1000 downloads are too big for both the number of dialogues to show, and for the zip file (dynamic requests have a limit of 32Mb). I think, for such a large volume, your best option is to use a proper feed and a feed reader. Maybe not so convenient for the user, but neither are 1000 download boxes.

Comment: I know it's a hard way to handle huge data, so as a first step, trying to download 2 files just for now.
Thanks to your advice, I almost succeeded to download 2 img by "window.open" script.
Actually it's not downloaded, but opened new windows with a target image. I guess it will be downloaded if it's a zip file format. 
Then I'll try to generate zip and find them if it's downloaded.

Comment: Try to add a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.jpg` header when serving the images, that should cause the browser to download them instead of displaying in the browser. But for zip or other files, it should start a download without that header.

Answer (score 0):

I reached the goal what I wanted to do.

As user interaction, generating html sources include below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("/download?url=http://dummy/sample1.jpg")
    window.open("/download?url=http://dummy/sample2.jpg")
</script>
```

then created new windows are handled with this code.

```
class DownloadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = self.request.get('url')
        filename = str(os.path.basename(url))
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/octet-stream'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (filename)

        data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        self.response.out.write(data)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/download', DownloadHandler)], debug=True)
```

Thank you, Attila.